# How do I get Alembic to emit a length constraint on a TEXT column?

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I'm not sure if it's actually called "length constraint", but I have a SQL statement that works when testing in a local docker container with mysql:

```sql
create unique index _uq_data on data(question_id, reply_id, text(50));
```

The constraint/length notation `(50)` is required since the TEXT field is variable length and may make the key too long. When creating a Flask migration for this I tried:

```py
op.create_unique_constraint('_data_uc', 'data', ['question_id', 'reply_id', 'text(50)'])
```

But the SQL that Alembic generates for this quotes the whole last field:

```sql
ALTER TABLE data ADD CONSTRAINT _data_uc UNIQUE (question_id, reply_id, `text(50)`);
```

which gives the error

```sql
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'text(50)' doesn't exist in table
```

How do I get this emitted as `'text'(50)` rather than `'text(50)'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently faced the same issue, I considered 2 solutions/workarounds.

### First solution

Alter your columns to specify a length to them. In your case, the columns seem to be IDs (as text), will they ever by longer than X characters ?

### Second solution

The `create_index` function allows [various things in the columns list](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/operations.html#alembic.operations.ops.CreateIndexOp.create_index), including `TextClause`. So you can create a ***non unique index*** with only a portion of the IDs, such as :

```python
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text
from alembic import op

def upgrade():
    op.create_index(
        "_uq_data",
        "data",
        # 100 is arbitrary, but there is a limit to index key length
        # depending on your mysql version and database configuration
        [text("question_id(100)"), text("reply_id(100)")],
        unique=False
    )
```

Resulting in the following SQL statement :

```sql
CREATE INDEX _uq_data ON data (question_id(100), reply_id(100))
```

### Alternative second solution

Still creating a "partial value index", but via sqlalchemy using [mysql dialect param `mysql_length`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#index-length) :

```python
Index(
    "_uq_data",
    "question_id",
    "reply_id",
    unique=False,
    mysql_length={"question_id": 100, "reply_id": 100},
    ),
```

Comment: The IDs do indeed have a maximum length, I'll give the first alternative a try when I have the chance.